# Different versions of mean value theorem in several variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

According to Calculus: A complete course by Adams & Essex, a version of the mean value theorem in several variables is given by

> If $f_1(a,b)$ and $f_2(a,b)$ [notation for partial derivatives] are continuous in a neighbourhood of the point $(a,b)$, and if the absolute values of $h$ and $k$ are sufficiently small, then there exist numbers $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, each between $0$ and $1$ such that $$f(a+h,b+k)-f(a,b)=hf_1(a+\theta_1 h,b+k)+kf_2(a,b+\theta_2 k)$$

Another version in the same book is given by

> If $f(x,y)$ has first partial derivatives continuous near every point of the straight line segment joining the points $(a,b)$ and $(a+h,b+k)$, then there exist a number $\theta$ between $0$ and $1$ such that $$f(a+h,b+k)=f(a,b)+hf_1(a+\theta h,b+\theta k)+kf_2(a+\theta h,b+\theta k)$$

What is the difference between these two versions? It seems like the conditions for the function $f$ are similiar.

Bonus question: Why can't the latter version be used to prove that continuous first partial derivatives of a function at a point imply that the function is differentiable at that point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: You should think about two different paths. One path is the line segment from $(a,b)$ to $(a+h,b+k)$. The other path is the two-segment path, going first in the $y$-direction from $(a,b)$ to $(a,b+k)$ and then in the $x$-direction from $(a,b+k)$ to $(a+h,b+k)$.

Comment: Is the two-segment path and the line segment path where the function $f$ is continuous, for each version respectively?In the latter version, the word "near" seems like the continuity can be extended to beyond this line segment.

Comment: Yes, you need stronger hypotheses in the first case than in the second ...

Comment: When proving that continuous first partial derivatives of a function imply differentiability of the function at say (a,b), one can estimate the fraction $\frac{f(a+h,b+k)-f(a,b)-hf_1(a,b)-f_2(a,b)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$ and use the first version of the mean value theorem above. What would go wrong if one were to use the second version?

Comment: How could one visualise the continuity requirement for $f$ in the second case? As consecutive open balls around every point on the line segment from $(a,b)$ to $(a+h,b+k)$? The first case seems clearer; an open ball around a single point, i.e. a disk.

Comment: You just need an open set containing the line segment. No big deal. With regard to your last question, you don't have information for all $(h,k)$ in a ball around $0$. You just have stuff along the line segment.

Comment: Okay. The word “near” still confuses somewhat. Are the endpoints on the line segment included? If so, would there not be continuity $\textit{near}$ $(a,b)=(0,0)$, and likewise at $(h,k)$, and so one would indeed have an open disc/ball around those points?

Comment: Yes, the endpoints are included.  The point is that the open ball at $(a,b)$ is likely to be small and not include the point $(a+h,b+k)$, whereas in the first description $(h,k)$ is small enough so that $(a+h,b+k)$ is by definition in the open ball.